# move_base.launch deprecated?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is move_base deprecated? If yes, what is the replacement?

when I do

$ roslaunch move_base move_base.launch

I get a lot of warnings like this:

[WARN] [WallTime: 1380536892.711000] You are launching the move_base_0.3_to_0.2.launch file which allows for a deprecated interface to move_base to be used. Please update your code and remove this launch file as soon as possible

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85216/move_base.launch-deprecated?/) by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2013-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That launch file is deprecated (as of 4 years ago! the navigation stack is now version 1.11, and that file was introduced when transitioning from 0.2 to 0.3)

Most people create a configuration for their specific robot, since there are a lot of parameters that can be tuned and tweaked for a specific robot. For a number of examples see: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/RobotsUsingNavStack

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-10-02**:
Thank you. However I see that there are still many examples on the wiki that suggest the use of move_base, for example here: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup

Maybe - I guess - I can ask more useful questions... :P

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-10-02**:
Maybe - I guess - I can ask more useful questions... :P

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-10-02**:
Yes, they are using move_base, but not that launch file. move_base is fully supported, that launch file is not really what you want, because it just remaps the old topic names/types to what is currently in move_base.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-01-20**:
Hi @fergs I have used a move_base.launch file given here http://www.hessmer.org/blog/2011/04/24/using-the-ros-navigation-stack/. Is it looks ok to you?